# iMac + Catalina : System Update stalls

Tags: imac, software-update

I have an iMac (bought in 2019), with macOS 10.15.7 and 16 GB of main memory. I don't have intentions to update to macOS 11 or higher, but I want to install security updates.

One day I noticed that my System Preferences mention updates pending. When I go to Software Update, I see the usual "Checking for Updates" box and a circling wheel next to it, which keeps trundling seemingly forever. Even after one hour or so, I don't see any change. No updates shown, no timeout error message displayed.

The iMac is connected to the Router via WLAN, and I don't block any ports on the router. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: In the Terminal, try `softwareupdate -l --include-config-data` to list updates. See https://eclecticlight.co/2019/07/12/how-do-you-get-a-security-update-to-work/

Comment: This does not work either. It says _Finding available software_ and then hangs. My impression is that my Mac  can't access the site which stores the software updates, but it is strange that there are no error messages.